# Rolling average on irregular series: based on averages or distributions

Tags: time-series, mean, moving-average

Maybe someone can give me a quick answer. When trying to find a simple measure for a rolling average for data processing, I found that many solutions in R seem to be just roll over the unique averages for each point in the sequence. This should inflate the influence of points with few data points in them over ones with many.

Is using rolling averages (even for simple visualizations) based on averages on averages and not averages of distributions a standard practice? (For example in using the average of averages of the years 1912-1917 for a rolling average measure instead of averaging over all the data points within this span.) Are there technical terms that distinguish between the two?

I will be grateful both for explanations and sources to find answers in.

**Update:** A reproducible R example of the difference below, also referred to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920814/r-rolling-average-from-irregular-time-series/

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2000,3),rep(2001,1),rep(2004,4),rep(2005,3),rep(2006,3), +
rep(2007,1),rep(2008,2),rep(2009,6),rep(2010,8)), + 
value1=floor(runif(31)*10), value2=floor(runif(31)*10),+
value3=floor(runif(31)*10))

rmeans <- data.frame()
for (i in (min(df$year)+2):(max(df$year)-2)){
  rmeans <- rbind(rmeans, data.frame(year=i,as.data.frame.list(colMeans(df +
[df$year>=(i-2)&df$year<(i+2),-c(1)]))))
}

df2 <- aggregate(cbind(value1,value2,value3)~year, FUN=mean, data=df)

rmeans2 <- data.frame()
for (i in (min(df2$year)+2):(max(df2$year)-2)){
  rmeans2 <- rbind(rmeans2, data.frame(year=i,as.data.frame.list(colMeans(df2 +
[df2$year>=(i-2)&df2$year<(i+2),-c(1)]))))
}

merge(rmeans,rmeans2,by="year",all.x=TRUE)

#results
  year value1.x value2.x value3.x value1.y value2.y value3.y
1 2002      3.5      2.0      4.5      4.0      2.3      6.0
2 2003      3.6      5.0      4.0      4.1      4.2      5.9
3 2004      2.4      6.0      3.4      2.3      6.1      3.5
4 2005      3.5      5.8      3.3      3.5      5.8      3.4
5 2006      3.4      5.5      3.5      3.1      4.9      3.8
6 2007      3.4      5.4      4.8      3.2      4.9      5.1
7 2008      4.9      4.4      4.8      4.2      4.2      5.2

#data
       year value1 value2 value3
1  2000      3      0      4
2  2000      1      0      2
3  2000      5      5      3
4  2001      5      3      9
5  2004      5      9      2
6  2004      6      8      0
7  2004      0      3      9
8  2004      2      2      0
9  2005      2      5      9
10 2005      2      9      2
11 2005      0      6      2
12 2006      9      4      4
13 2006      9      8      2
14 2006      0      4      3
15 2007      2      2      5
16 2008      7      6      7
17 2008      0      5      9
18 2009      8      8      6
19 2009      9      6      1
20 2009      3      0      3
21 2009      2      9      9
22 2009      2      1      8
23 2009      8      0      1
24 2010      1      8      1
25 2010      4      2      2
26 2010      7      5      0
27 2010      1      7      2
28 2010      4      3      1
29 2010      1      7      4
30 2010      0      0      5
31 2010      4      2      9
```

Comment: Could you show some numbers to show what you mean by *rolling averages* and *averages of averages*?  Are these the same as [moving averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)?

Comment: I added an R example with data and results of averages below. x is over distributions, y is over averages. I do think that x is what is normally meant  by moving averages as you cite, however technically, i've seen them actually do y, and some packages in R seem to encourage that.